# Access Pages from MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a page which contains certain controls such as text boxes and buttons. I am trying to access the properties of these controls to display text in them.

I am able to access their properties, however I am having troubles actually getting the values to work.

So far I have this:

```
Pages.pgEditPlayer editPlayerPage = new Pages.pgEditPlayer();
editPlayerPage.txtPlayerName.Text = "Hello, World";
```

This lets me access the text box without any errors, however when I check to see if the text box has been updated, it doesn't display 'Hello, World'. Does anyone know why this could be?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ZimbuyeManagementApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Zimbuye Management Application" Height="358.955" Width="738.433">

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="views">
            <x:XData>
                <Views xmlns="">
                    <View>
                        <Page Source="Pages\pgAddPlayer.xaml"/>
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        <Page Source="Pages\pgRemovePlayer.xaml"/>
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        <Page Source="Pages\pgEditPlayer.xaml"/>
                    </View>
                </Views>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSource" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource views},  XPath=Views/View}"/>
        <Storyboard x:Key="slideLeftToRight" TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" AccelerationRatio=".4" DecelerationRatio=".4">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="viewer" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="512" To="0" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bordervisual" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="0" To="-512" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="slideRightToLeft" TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" AccelerationRatio=".4" DecelerationRatio=".4">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="viewer" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="-512" To="0" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bordervisual" Duration="0:0:0.6" From="0" To="512" />
        </Storyboard>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="VisualBrush1" Visual="{Binding ElementName=viewer}" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="frmMain" Loaded="frmMain_Loaded">
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
            <TabItem Width="128" FontSize="18" Height="128">

                <TabItem.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Sythnet-PC\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ZimbuyeManagementApplication\ZimbuyeManagementApplication\Images\home.png"></ImageBrush>
                </TabItem.Background>

                <StackPanel Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="Zimbuye Management Application" FontFamily="comic sans ms" FontSize="24"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtWelcomeMessage" Text="Welcome!" FontFamily="comic sans ms" FontSize="16"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtAuthor" Margin="5"> Author </TextBlock>
                        </Border>

                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtAppName" Margin="5"> Application Name </TextBlock>
                        </Border>

                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtVersionNumber" Margin="5"> Version Number </TextBlock>
                        </Border>

                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtStartDate" Margin="5"> Start Date </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Create Player" Width="128" FontSize="18" Height="128">

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="26"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lstPlayers" Width="250" SelectionChanged="lstPlayers_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="txtSearch" Width="250" TextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid Name="ViewGrid" Height="512" Width="512">
                            <Border x:Name="bordervisual" Width="512">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="rectanglevisual" />
                                <Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform />
                                </Border.RenderTransform>
                            </Border>

                            <ItemsControl x:Name="viewer" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Page}" Margin="0,0,0,1">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Frame x:Name="frame" Source="{Binding XPath=@Source}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform />
                                </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                            </ItemsControl>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Ellipse Width="32" Height="32" MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown_1" Margin="10">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF6E8AE8" />
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>

                                <Ellipse Width="32" Height="32" MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown_2" Margin="10">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF6E8AE8" />
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>

                                <Ellipse Width="32" Height="32" MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown_3" Margin="10">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF6E8AE8" />
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lblPlayerName" Height="26" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Name: "/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lblPlayerSurname" Height="26" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Surname:"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lblPlayerAge" Height="26" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Age: "/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lblPlayerCode" Height="26" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Code: "/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lblPlayerStatus" Height="26" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Status: "/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Create Team" Width="128" FontSize="18" Height="128">
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Assign Players" Width="128" FontSize="18" Height="128">
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Admin" Width="128" FontSize="18" Height="128"  Visibility="Hidden">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Because you create another instance. Where the page displayed?

Comment: The page is on the MainWindow

Comment: How are you adding it to the main window?

Comment: It's done through the XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**access current page from a Frame:**

```
((Pages.pgEditPlayer)frame.Content).txtPlayerName.Text = "Hello, World";
```

**EDIT:**

in this case, We need to extract the Frame element from DataTemplate. (Just for the challenge, because it seems a little crazy)

```
var Pages = new Page[viewer.Items.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < Pages.Length ; i++)
{
     var contentPrs = (ContentPresenter)viewer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
     contentPrs.ApplyTemplate();

     var template = contentPrs.ContentTemplate;
     var currFrame = (Frame)template.FindName("frame", contentPrs );
     Pages[i] = (Page)currFrame.Content;
 }

((Pages.pgEditPlayer)Pages.First(p => p is pgEditPlayer)).txtPlayerName.Text = "";
```

Hope that works ...

Comment: 'frame' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: How would I go about solving that then?

Comment: i added solution for this case.

Comment: 'System.Windows.Controls.Page' does not contain a definition for 'txtPlayerName' and no extension method 'txtPlayerName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Page' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The last line of code doesn't work, if this error message means anything to you...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to call the instance that belongs to the MainWindow:

In code-behind of your main window:

```
this.MyPage.txtPlayerName.Text = "Hello, World";
```

Comment: Nope, I don't seem to have a any of the pages after the this.

Comment: Hmm, where are you needing to set this text? MainWindow?

Comment: I'm changing it from the MainWindow, however the page itself is in a navigation window which is displayed on the MainWindow

Comment: Ok, so you have window that holds a page inside the mainwindow? I'll update my answer for you to try something

Comment: Yeah, but I still don't have access to that nav window

Comment: Can we see the code(xaml) where you have set the nav window inside the mainwindow?

Comment: Will add all the XAML now to the top post

Comment: Hmm, I don't usually set my views up this way usually I have main window that holds a contentcontrol and then in the mainwindowviewmodel I can bind the contentcontrol to an abstract type in which all my views implement an IView. I'm sorry I can be of more assistance. Can you try to put names on your 'Pages' in this window?